# three column header needs to respond to a two column one with middle column below outer ones

Tags: css, flexbox

Very typical header consisting of "LOGO | MENU | ICON" needs to respond to "LOGO | ICON" in a row, with MENU below that row.

I tried Flexbox but I don't see anything that can bump down the middle box (in this case, the menu).

```css
div#left {
  width: 397px;
  float: left;
  background: red;
  color: white;
}

div#middle {
  min-width: 955px;
  float: left;
  background: gray;
  color: white;
}

div#right {
  width: 88px;
  float: left;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="left">LOGO</div>
<div id="middle">MENU</div>
<div id="right">ICON</div>
```

http://brinsterinc.com/three_column_responsive.html

I need the MENU to move below the LOGO | ICON when the window is not wide enough to show everything. Thanks!

Comment: Share your code

Comment: I created a snippet of what you linked please update with the proper if it is not correct

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order is what you're after. Consider looking at a framework like Tailwind or Bootstrap too.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps flex can work with the sizes and a wrap.  No need for the floating with the `space-between` then

Note I also used classes rather than id's to style as a more flexible pattern - and have a header element wrapping it for the style.

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex: 397px 1 88px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.left {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

.middle {
  min-width: 955px;
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
}

.right {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="left">LOGO</div>
  <div class="middle">MENU</div>
  <div class="right">ICON</div>
</header>
```